# Question Regarding : FutureWarning:In a future version of pandas all arguments of DataFrame.drop except for the argument 'labels' will be keyword-only

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and using Pandas library. As a practise i was trying to clean a excel file and when I executed the code I see the below,

FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of DataFrame.drop except for the argument 'labels' will be keyword-only
data_one_clean = active_employee.drop(active_employee.columns[0:3], 1)
not sure how to fix this.

My code:

import pandas

```
active_employee = pandas.read_excel("All Active Employee.xlsx", sheet_name=0)
data_one_clean = active_employee.drop(active_employee.columns[0:3], 1)
data_two_clean = data_one_clean.drop(data_one_clean.columns[1:10], 1)
data_three_clean = data_two_clean.drop(data_two_clean.columns[2], 1)
data_final = data_three_clean.drop(data_three_clean.columns[3:], 1)
```

print(data_final)

Comment: What version of pandas are you running? Use `pd.__version__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can be flexible when you define and call a function.

From the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), the `drop()` function looks like this:

```
drop(
    labels=None,
    axis=0,
    index=None,
    columns=None,
    level=None,
    inplace=False,
    errors="raise",
)
```

These are the parameters you can use to call the function and their default values. Right now, when you call the function, you can use the parameter names or their positions. Your code is using their positions:

```
active_employee.drop(active_employee.columns[0:3], 1)
```

This gives 2 parameters which are mapped to the first two parameters in the definition: `labels` and `axis`. You can make the same call by explicitly naming the parameters:

```
active_employee.drop(labels=active_employee.columns[0:3], axis=1)
```

This also lets you cherry-pick which parameters you want to use. For example you can specify the level like this, leaving all the other values at their defaults:

```
active_employee.drop(labels=active_employee.columns[0:3], level=1)
```

The warning is telling you that future versions will not support the first approach. So to fix the warning, just add `axis=` before the `1` in all your calls to drop.